# Error compiling Firefox for Android on a 64-bit Linux machine

Tags: android, linux, firefox, x86

I was trying to compile Fennec (Firefox for Android) when I ended up with this:
http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2126890

almost as soon as I started.

Then, I came to know that this is an issue with the ia32-libs multiarch on Linux. Since, the build tool uses a 32-bit Android NDK to compile code via a 64-bit machine (the one I am running), it relies on ia32-libs. Soon, I was left with no option to continue making a build as ia32-libs under Ubuntu/Debian has underwent a lot of change recently and has broken support (that's what I got to know).

Can anyone tell me if I can still make a build because a lot of other machines with similar specifications (to the ones mentioned below) are able to do it.

Any alternative to 32-bit NDK (like a 64-bit one)..?

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, all updated with 3GB RAM.